# OpenGL - pixel color wrong

Tags: c++, opengl

I draw a red triangle that is half the screen (screen is 1024*768, background color is black). I then read the color of each pixel using glReadPixels. There should be 1024*768/2 pixels with (r = 255, g = 0, b = 0) since the red triangle is half the size of the screen, and the remaining of the pixels should be (r = 0, g = 0, b = 0) . However, there is a small number of pixels that are neither (r = 255, g = 0, b = 0) nor (r = 0, g = 0, b = 0):

- some are (r = 64, g = 0, b = 0)
- some are (r = 128, g = 0, b = 0)
- and some are (r = 191, g = 0, b = 0)

Do you know what could be happening?

This is my fragment shader:

```
in vec3 fragmentColor;

out vec3 color;

void main(){

        color = vec3(1,0.,0.);
}
```

and this is how I read the color of the pixel:

```
unsigned char *mycolor = (unsigned char *)malloc(3*width_here*height_here*sizeof(unsigned char *));

glReadPixels(0, 0, width_here, height_here, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)(mycolor));
```

Comment: Anti-aliasing?  The different colored pixels are those that are near the ideal line, but are drawn in different shades so that the line appears to the human eye to look more like a line rather than a staircase.

Comment: Sounds like you have multisampling turned on (see [this page](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/28_antialiasing_and_multisampling/index.php) for MS vs non-MS)

Comment: You're using the `sizeof` operator wrong. `sizeof(sometype*)` returns the size of a pointer to that type, not the size of the type itself. And `sizeof(char)` is **defined** to be 1. Hence you're allocating more memory than is required to hold the data read.

Comment: The anti-aliasing/multisampling solution worked. Thanks!